# Grails databinding problem

Tags: data-binding, grails

What is missing here because when a validation fail the rendered page doesnt show the previous introduced values so the user cant correct it. Please update my code with the missing code! Everything is working properly, except when returning after a validation fail the previous introduced values are gone.

add.gsp

```
    <div id="stylized" class="myform">
<g:form controller="conference" action="save">
<h1>Add New Conference Record</h1>
<p>Basic Information</p>

<label>Name
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="name" /><br>

...
...

<p>Dates</p>

<label>Start Date
<span class="small">First Day</span>
</label>
<g:datePicker name="startDate" precision="day" value="${new Date()}"/><br><br>

<label>End Date
<span class="small">First Day</span>
</label>
<g:datePicker name="endDate" precision="day" value="${new Date()}"/><br><br>


...
...

<g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" id="addConference"/>


<div class="spacer"></div>
  </g:form>

                <g:hasErrors bean="${conferenceInstance}">
            <div class="errors">
                <g:renderErrors bean="${conferenceInstance}" as="list" />
            </div>
            </g:hasErrors>

</div>
```

ConferenceController

```
  def save = {
        def conferenceInstance = new Conference(params)
        if (conferenceInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'conference.label', default: 'Cferenceon'), conferenceInstance.id])}"
            redirect(action: "/index")
        }
        else {
            render(view: "add", model: [conferenceInstance: conferenceInstance])
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Teach a Man to Fish" Answer

Grails scaffolding shows the previous values when validation fails, so the easiest way to see how this should work would be to run:

```
grails generate-all Conference
```

Then study the code of the generated controller and GSPs.

---

### Spoon-Feeding Answer

The problem is in your GSP code, if you specify

```
<g:datePicker name="startDate" precision="day" value="${new Date()}"/>
```

the date-picker will always shows today's date. Similarly, this text field will always be blank:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

because you have not specified a `value` attribute.

When validation fails, you need to get the values from the bean that failed validation, so replace the above with:

```
<g:datePicker name="startDate" precision="day" value="${conferenceInstance?.date}"/>
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="${conferenceInstance?.name}"/>
```

Comment: thanks man. i'll try it right now but the way you put it, im sure it will 100% work. Every1 should explain like you do :p thanks a lot

Comment: @John you're welcome, do you mind if I get a t-shirt printed with the quote "Every1 should explain like you do – John"

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if that works..

```
   <div id="stylized" class="myform">
<g:form controller="conference" action="save">
<h1>Add New Conference Record</h1>
<p>Basic Information</p>

<label>Name
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="${conferenceInstance.name}/><br>

...
...

<p>Dates</p>

<label>Start Date
<span class="small">First Day</span>
</label>
<g:datePicker name="startDate" precision="day" value="${conferenceInstance.startDate}"/><br><br>

<label>End Date
<span class="small">First Day</span>
</label>
<g:datePicker name="endDate" precision="day" value="${conferenceInstance.endDate}"/><br><br>


...
...

<g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" id="addConference"/>


<div class="spacer"></div>
  </g:form>

                <g:hasErrors bean="${conferenceInstance}">
            <div class="errors">
                <g:renderErrors bean="${conferenceInstance}" as="list" />
            </div>
            </g:hasErrors>

</div>
```

Comment: ok i'll try both the cases. btw the diference between both is the '?' adter conferenceInstance. What really that means?

Comment: Actually, the '?' char is important, I forgot it! If the conferenceInstance is null, using the '?' char prevent a nullPointerException to be thrown.